# Reserved keys for user meta in wordpress - About me

Tags: php, wordpress, key, meta

Does anyone know which meta keys are reserved (that I cannot use for my own purposes) in wordpress, if any?

Also, for the wordpress about me section. Does anyone know how to call that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reserved Terms: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Post Meta Keys:

You probably don't want to use the following *post meta* keys:

- `_thumbnail_id` - Used to store the featured image ID
- `_edit_last`    - Used by the *Heartbeat API*
- `_edit_lock`  - Used by the *Heartbeat API*
- `_wp_page_template` - Stores the page template.
- `_wp_attached_file`
- `_wp_attachment_metadata`
- `_menu_item_{url, object, object_id, target, classes, xfn, ... }`

as your custom meta keys, as they might be overwritten by the WordPress Core.

### User Meta Keys:

Similarly for these *user meta* keys:

- `first_name`
- `last_name`
- `nickname`
- `description`
- `rich_editing`
- `comment_shortcuts`
- `admin_color`
- `jabber`
- `aim`
- `yim`
- `default_password_nag`
- `use_ssl`
- `show_admin_bar_front`
- `show_welcome_panel`
- `dismissed_wp_pointers`
- `nav_menu_recently_edited`
- `managenav-menuscolumnshidden`
- `closedpostboxes_{post, dashboard, page, ...}`
- `metaboxhidden_{post, dashboard, page,  ...}`
- `meta-box-order_{post, dashboard, page,  ...}`
- `screen_layout_{post, dashboard, page, ...}`

and the following user meta keys that have the default table prefix:

- `wp_capabilities`
- `wp_user_level`
- `wp_dashboard_quick_press_last_post_id`
- `wp_user-settings`
- `wp_user-settings-time`

So in general, I would suggest you to **prefix** your own meta keys, to avoid clashes with the WordPress core or other plugins or themes.

### How To Display The User Meta Keys?

If you want to display all the user meta keys, for the current user, you can use:

```
print_r( array_keys( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id() ) ) );
```

with an output like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first_name
    [1] => last_name
    [2] => nickname
    [3] => description
    [4] => rich_editing
    [5] => comment_shortcuts
    [6] => admin_color
    [7] => use_ssl
    [8] => show_admin_bar_front
    ...cut...
)
```

Check out the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) to get more information about the [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) function.

Or just investigate your `wp_usermeta` table.

### A Simple Plugin To View The Metadata For Each User:

It's useful to be able to view the metadata for each user, so let's create a simple plugin for that.

Here's a screenshot from a user's profile/edit page:

[image: User Meta View]

and here's the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: A Simple User Meta Data Viewer
 * Description: This plugin allows the site admin to view the metadata for each user, in the edit user screen
 * Author:      birgire
 * Version:     0.0.1
 * Plugin URI:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25316090/2078474
 */

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'birgire_usermeta_list' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'birgire_usermeta_list' );

function birgire_usermeta_list( $profileuser )
{
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
    {
        // Fetch all the user meta data for current profile user:
        $items = get_user_meta( $profileuser->ID );

        // Loop:
        $rows = '';
        foreach( $items as $key => $item )
        {
                $rows .= sprintf( '
                        <tr>
                            <th>%s</th>
                            <td><input type="text" value="%s" readonly="readonly" class="regular-text" /></td>
                       </tr>',
                    $key,
                    esc_attr( array_shift( $item ) )
                );
        }

        // Output:
        printf( '<h3>%s</h3><table class="form-table"><tbody>%s</tbody></table>', 
            __( 'User Meta' ),
            $rows   
        );

    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Can I ask, do you know of anywhere that I can see a complete list of the reserved wordpress meta keys. I would love to see what is available to use.

Comment: I'm not sure such a Codex list exists for meta keys, but I just went through my `wp_postmeta` table on a plain vanilla install ;-) Why don't you just prefix your meta keys?

Comment: ahh, sorry I see now that you mention user meta, not post meta ;-) I will update the answer ;-)